# control chalice IP connection to postgres

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, chalice

I built a small chalice app that is connected to Postgres that does some inserts. In the pg_hba.conf file (the database is on another server) I have allowed only certain IPs to connect. Almost every request from lambda uses a different IP.

this is my chalice app

```
import psycopg2.extras
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
from chalice import Chalice, Response
app = Chalice(app_name='hello_world')
app.debug = True

conn = psycopg2.connect(user='user',
                        password='Password123',
                        host='123.12.12.123',
                        port=5432,
                        database='test_db')

cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
@app.route("/")
def main_page():
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM main WHERE status=1")
    g = dict(cursor.fetchone())
    return {"count": g['count']}
```

it works when I deploy local on `127.0.0.1` , is there a way to manage lambda IP when connecting to the database?

I am open to any suggestions

Comment: Where is your psql db located?

Comment: @jellycsc on another ec2 instance

Comment: Cool, you can run your lambda inside VPC and connect to your psql using a private IP.

Comment: @jellycsc can you please show how in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Create your vpc, private subnet, public subnets, security groups, etc.

Note: This is the challenging part.

Tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html

Then copy the `security-groups-id` and `subnets` to chalice config: `.chalice/config.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "app_name": "XYZ",
  "stages": {
    "prod": {
      "security_group_ids": [
        "sg-YYYYYYYY"
      ],
      "subnet_ids": [
        "subnet-XXXXXXXX"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```